how to get html5-qrcode to recognize qrcodes in react?
I am developing a react.js app with node.js at the backend.
I want to use a QR Code reader to scan a code that contains a json-object but for some reason QR Codes aren't recognized when I put the scanner over them and I don't know why.
I use

node.js in version 21.7.3
html5-qrcode module in ^2.3.8
react in ^18.2.0

Here my QRCodeScannerPanel component
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import QRCodeScanner from './QRCodeScanner';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './QRCodeScannerPanel.css'; // Import the CSS file

class QRCodeScannerPanel extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        console.log("QRCodeScannerPanel: Constructor");
        console.log(props);
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            scannedValue: null,
            panelMounted: false // Add state variable to track panel mounting
        };
        this.handleScanSuccess = this.handleScanSuccess.bind(this);
        this.handleClosePanel = this.handleClosePanel.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("QRCodeScannerPanel: Component mounted");
        // Update state to indicate panel is mounted
        this.setState({ panelMounted: true });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log("QRCodeScannerPanel: Component unmounted");
    }

    handleScanSuccess(decodedText, decodedResult) {
        console.log("QRCodeScannerPanel: Scan success - Decoded Text:", decodedText);
        console.log("QRCodeScannerPanel: Scan success - Decoded Text:", decodedResult);
        // Pass the scanned value to the parent component
        this.props.onScanSuccess(decodedText);
        // Close the panel after successful scan
        this.handleClosePanel();
    }

    handleClosePanel(errorMessage, error) {
        console.log("QRCodeScannerPanel: Closing panel");
        console.log("QRCodeScannerPanel: ",errorMessage);
        // Close the panel by calling the onClose callback passed from the parent component
        this.props.onClose();
    }

    render() {
        console.log("QRCodeScannerPanel: Rendering panel");
        // Conditionally render QRCodeScanner based on panel mounting state
        return (
            <div className="qrScannerPanel">
                <div className="overlay" onClick={this.handleClosePanel}></div>
                <div className="panel">
                    <Button variant="danger" className="closeButton" onClick={this.handleClosePanel}>X</Button>
                    {this.state.panelMounted && <QRCodeScanner
                            fps={20}
                            qrbox={250}
                            verbose={false}
                            disableFlip={false}
                            qrCodeSuccessCallback={this.handleScanSuccess}
                    />}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default QRCodeScannerPanel;

And my QRCodeScanner component.
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Html5QrcodeScanner } from "html5-qrcode";
import './QRCodeScanner.css'; // Import the CSS file for styling

const qrcodeRegionId = "qr-code-full-region";


const createConfig  = (props) => {
    console.log("QRCodeScanner: Creating scanner configuration");
    const { fps, qrbox, aspectRatio, disableFlip } = props;
    let config = {};
    if (fps) config.fps = fps;
    if (qrbox) config.qrbox = qrbox;
    if (aspectRatio) config.aspectRatio = aspectRatio;
    if (disableFlip !== undefined) config.disableFlip = disableFlip;
    //config.rememberLastUsedCamera = true;
    //config.showTorchButtonIfSupported = true;
    //config.showZoomSliderIfSupported = true;
    //config.defaultZoomValueIfSupported = true;
    console.log("QRCodeScanner: Configuration created:", config);
    return config;
}

const QRCodeScanner = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        // when component mounts
        console.log("QRCodeScanner: Initializing scanner");
        const config = createConfig(props);
        const verbose = props.verbose === true;
        
        // Suceess callback is required.
        if (!(props.qrCodeSuccessCallback)) {
            throw new Error("qrCodeSuccessCallback is required callback.");
        }
        const html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(qrcodeRegionId, config, verbose);
        html5QrcodeScanner.render(props.qrCodeSuccessCallback, props.qrCodeErrorCallback);
        console.log("QRCodeScanner: Scanner initialized");

        // cleanup function when component will unmount
        return () => {
            html5QrcodeScanner.clear().catch(error => {
                console.error("Failed to clear html5QrcodeScanner. ", error);
            });
        };
    });

    return (
        <div id={qrcodeRegionId} className="qrcode-scanner-container"/>
    );
};

export default QRCodeScanner;

To my intentions:

I want to retrieve a certain property from that object and return that value to a text input in the DOM. The value is used to retrieve a record from a database with the value provided by the text input.

For that purpose I built a component that consists of a three elements. the text input, a search button for manual search operations, a QR code button for scan searches.

upon clicking of the QR code button I include a panel in the render function. the purpose is to darken the background and display the QR Code scanning field in the center. When a code is scanned the panel must return the json-object to the text input and perform a search.

the above points work all except that the qrCodeSuccessCallback us never called.


Other Info:

I only took inspiration from the online resources explaining how to implement the component.
I enabled https with a self signed certificate.
On mobile I can retrieve the camera permissions
I also passed a qrCodeErrorCallback function at some point which got called once the code reaches the html5QrcodeScanner.render function, which is called instantly and I don't know how to handle that yet.
I tried older version of the qrcode component but then I get an error that there are no exports available and I don't know how to fix that.
I also tried the react-qr-reader in ^3.0.0-beta-1 but it didn't work, although the details elude me now.
from what I know the html5-qrcode module is based on zxing.

I want the scanner to scan continuously and eventually report success and call qrCodeSuccessCallback when I put a QR code in front of it.
I have generated some test codes which work with regular apps from the app store.
I am not an expert with react. Do I need to handle this differently?
I am also open to substituting the module with another, if anyone can give me a recommendation it would be appreciated.
